# Gratitude Comment Missing

Tags: discussion

Someone [thanked me for contributing content](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/29474/what-guidelines-are-there-for-programmers-wanting-to-learn-ui-skills/29479#29479) to this website. Now that comment is missing. I linked to it on my portfolio website. Where'd it go? Bring it back.

I don't care who deleted it. I don't care that they're abusing their moderator powers. I won't go into detail about how mean that was.

Comment: related post: http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/including-thanks-in-your-questions/1183

Answer (score 13):

I have just checked the deleted comments against that post. There were two comments that have both been removed; one was someone saying thanks to you for posting the answer, the other comment was your reply to the previous comment thanking that person for thanking you.

Both of these comments are just noise and provide no benefit of any nature to the answer so would have been deleted.

Thanking people for questions and answers is done by voting up those posts. If everyone were to post 'thanks' against every question / answer they appreciated then the site would be filled with useless noise.

This is covered by the [Privileges](https://ux.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) section of the site (emphasis mine):

> ## When *shouldn't* I comment?
>
> Comments are not recommended for any of the following:
>
> - Suggesting corrections that don't fundamentally change the meaning of the post; instead, make or suggest an edit;
> - Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one);
> - **Compliments which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, up-vote it and pay it forward;**
> - Criticisms which do not add anything constructive ("-1, see previous comments you scallywag!"); instead, down-vote (and provide or up-vote a better answer if appropriate);
> - Secondary discussion or debating a controversial point; please use chat instead;
> - Discussion of community behavior or site policies; please use meta instead.

Comment: It's not noise to me. It's important to me. It's not noise to everyone reading my portfolio website. It's very important that they see that. You're just rationalizing deplorable behavior after the fact. Readers will want to see that their answers are appreciated. You're ruining the emotional, human component of this user experience. We're not your robot answer slaves. People expect recognition and appreciation in return for their effort. Bring the comments back.

Comment: Based on your premise, there should be no point system at all, rewarding users for their answers.

Comment: Thanks for the week ban by the way. Your reasoning was that many of most posts have flags. I'm the one who flags all my posts. Your only other reason was that I was being abusive. A person started attacking me with abusive comments. His comments were removed by moderators because they were abusive. My comments stayed because they weren't abusive. So essentially you banned me from this website for no good reason. And you're ruining my reputation. Great job JonW.

Comment: JonW actually *is* doing a great job. As far as I remember the ban reason had to do with a lot of low-quality posts, and judging from the stats of your questions, it sounds about right (it sums up at -18 at the moment, not including activity on Meta). Your answers get good upvotes though.

Comment: You don't get to see who else has flagged your posts so you would not know how many flags your posts have received. Anyone is able to flag any post, but that is completely private and the flags only gets seen by the diamond moderators (and SE administrators).

Comment: The comment provides my answer greater credibility by social proofing me with both programming and UX experience, increasing the chance of someone following my instructions and learning more about UX, increasing the chance they'll contribute more to this website.

Comment: I'll continue contributing quality answers to this website if I know comments thanking me won't be deleted. Doesn't that sound fair to you?

Comment: Would you like us to update the FAQ? We'll just add a caveat to the bit Jon quoted, and say "that's unless you're Tyler Langan, who *is* allowed to post such comments, seeing as he  threatened to stop using the site otherwise". Jon, could you talk to the administrators about updating that part ASAP?

Comment: @TylerLangan Please stop trolling our site that we actually use for productive reasons. Find someone else to bother.